# CSS Styling with translate, left , right

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
  .dropdown-menu-center {
  left: 50% !important;
  right: auto !important;
 -- text-align: center !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
}
</style>
```

I'm trying to center the drilldown list for the dropdown button with bootstrap 4... can someone explain this style ? My understanding that translate uses x and y axis..why would left 50% be used ? why cant i just put translate(50%,0) to replace left ? or just used left 50% and right auto , wouldn't it be placed at center?

Comment: can you please add the html so we can help :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/ysterysys/pen/dzQKWL?editors=1010 ..heres the html..im just dont get how that styling works , since its the same if i replace left with translate ..why would i need translate , left & right together..

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question, not an external link, you should be able to edit your own question. External links are ok for working demo **in addition** to code in the question, but SO snippets, the `<>` button in the editor, are even better.

Answer (score 2):

The `right` property in your sample doesn't matter - ignore that for a moment.

The `left: 50%` in your sample states that the element should be **offset** by 50%. This means that simply adding `left: 50%` will place the left edge of `.dropdown-menu-center` in the exact middle, with the center of the element being right of that (specifically, half of the page `width` plus half of the element `width`).

This is countered with `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`, which moves the element left by 50% of its `width`. Thus, combining this with `left: 0` places the center of `.dropdown-menu-center` in the exact center of the page.

However, it's critical to note that this will **only** work if you use either [**relative positioning**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning) or [**absolute positioning**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning):

```css
.dropdown-menu-center {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu-center"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: right ! but if you used left:50% , it's offset by 50% , which is centered, why is there a need for translate  to center it again?

Comment: Because otherwise the **left edge** of the element will be in the center. The **center** of the element will be at something like 60% from the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you want place div in center of another, you must be use this equation: (**DIV_A** / 2) - (**DIV_B** / 2).
**DIV_A** represent the container and **DIV_B** the content.

Its same for height property.

Your case is the same operation

```
 left: 50%; // (DIV_A / 2)
 transform: translate(-50%,0); // - ( DIV_B / 2 )
```